# Matrix, Quardratic form and boundedness

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ symmetric matrix. Is this set $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: x^TAx=1\}$ bounded?($x^T$ stands for transpose of the vector $x$)

Comment: If you pick as $A$ to be the matrix that is everywhere 0 other than $A_{1,1} = 1$, the set is unbounded since any $x$ with $x_1 = 1$ lies in the set.

Answer (score 1):

Since $A$ can be diagonalized orthogonally we have

$$A=P^TDP $$
where $D$ is diagonal, and $P$ is orthogonal. The set in question then becomes

$$\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n:(Px)^TD(Px)=1\}=:A $$
which is the image under $P^{-1}=P^T$ of the simpler set

$$B:=\{y \in \mathbb{R}^n:y^TDy=1\} $$

It follows that if one of the eigenvalues of $A$ is zero, then $B$ is unbounded in some direction, and thus $A$ is also unbounded in that case. The converse is true as well.